# Laravel add foreign key on migration file

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.1

i have this structure on `card_price` table in database:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `card_price` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `card_price` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `user_id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

and this structure for `users`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `family` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

i'm creating this tables with `migration` files such as:

`card_price`:

```
Schema::create('card_price',function(Blueprint $table){
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('card_price');
    $table->tinyInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

and `users`:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name','20');
    $table->string('family','25');
    $table->string('username','15');
    $table->string('password','64');
    $table->string('email','20');
    $table->string('remember_token','100');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

with this migration files i'm trying to create foreign key with `user_id` on `card_price` table and `id` on `users` table. unfortunately i get this error:

```
  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL
  : alter table `card_price` add constraint card_price_user_id_foreign foreig
  n key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`))

  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

Comment: so your data says no no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because of data type mismatch in foreign table. You should use same data type for parent and child table table column referencing it.

Change  data type of `user_id` in `card_price` table to `INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL`;

First Alter your table with following query:

```
ALTER TABLE `card_price` 
CHANGE COLUMN `user_id` `user_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ;
```

query for foreign key  reference:

```
ALTER TABLE `card_price` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_users`
  FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
  REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

Comment: yes yes. Btw the (10) is display width and not necessary. Can you show him the `Alter Table` to perform this? The data can still be wrong to support the FK creation. But you are right

Comment: @Code-Monk `user_id` in `card_price` is `$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();` and i get same error

Comment: @mahdi pishguy: check once.

Comment: @Drew: Above queries works fine and you are right about the - The size and sign of integer types must be the same. The length of string types need not be the same.

Comment: i am with you. We need to get OP to believe it :)

Comment: @Drew: Special Thanks to you also :)

Comment: Welcome  mahdi pishguy

Comment: dang monk I was wrong (my comment under question). It was the structure. That is why I hung in there :)